# Dynamically creating and populating class inside method in java

Tags: java, reflection

Though my question seems repetition, but I am new to Reflections and could find solution to the exact problem.
I need to write a method, which any class can call to populate its data. For simplicity, I created a class say MappingHelper, with a Factory like method 'Create' which will create its own instance. I need to then populate this instance and return it.

```
public final Class MappingHelper{
public final Object getBENodeData(Class<?> classRef, String className){
   Class myClass = Class.forName(classRef.getName());
   Method method = classRef.getMethod("Create",(Class<?>[])null);
   Object obj =  method.invoke(null, (Object[]) null);
 }
}
```

I need to typecast obj to same type as of 'classRef' so that I can call its instance methods.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible with reflection and with your current setup. Even if you manage to cast the object to `classRef`, you wouldn't know what instance methods to call since `getBENodeData` presumably can take any type.

What you can do is call the method from a location where the type is known, and cast to it.

```
Object obj = getBENodeData(MyType1.class, MyType1.class.getName());
MyType1 myType1 = (MyType1) obj;
myType1.setId(..);

Object obj2 = getBENodeData(MyType2.class, MyType2.class.getName());
MyType2 myType2 = (MyType2) obj2;
myType2.setName(..);
```